# How to package tarballs in tarballs with Maven

Tags: maven, tar, maven-assembly-plugin

So there are some folders that I would like to compress into tar.gz file individually, and then collectively compress them into a tar.gz file. Is there some way of doing this in maven?

Edit: I'm aware of the assembly plugin for Maven.
To my knowledge if you have something like:

```
<assembly>
  <id>src</id>
  <formats>
     <format>tar.gz</format>
  </formats>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>src</directory>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

It would simply include the "src" folder within the project tar file.
What I want to know is how you would create a tar of the src folder before it's added into the project's tar file.

Comment: have you attempted anything at this point?

Comment: @OrionRogue So far I've tried to create separate assembly files for each folder. This would only put the folders into the resulting project tar instead of having the folder being a tar file within the project tar file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tar itself is just a file which is a resource that the other tar can reference. if your build is trying to create a tar for one purpose, then an assembly that contains that tar, I would suggest creating an ant script that you run from the maven build that does the recursion.

If you have a tar on the machine somewhere and you just want to include it, the assembly can add that file.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into that tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a [Maven assembly](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html) as seen here with the bin descriptor.

There is also reference here on SO for [creating tar files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097170/maven-assembly-plugin-not-creating-tar-files-with-directory-entries)